# How to add a specific sidebar to meteor route?

Tags: meteor, routes, handlebars.js

For example I have an admin area and I want to display a specific sidebar for admin navigation

```
<body>
  {{#if adminRoute}}
    {{> sidebarAdminNav }}
    {{> yeld }}
  {{else}}
    {{> yeld }}
  {{/if}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for are called nested views. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25926717/1439597) gives the best option I have used so far. It is no "angular ui-router" ideal, but it does the job. In your layout:

```
  {{#if layout.renderSidebar}}
    {{> sidebarAdminNav }}
  {{/if}}
  {{> yield }}
```

And in *each* (sadly) of your admin routes:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      layout: {renderSidebar: true},
      ...
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some packages are available for sidebars in meteor.

```
https://atmospherejs.com/jelena/meteor-sidebar-transitions
https://github.com/awatson1978/semantic-ui-sidebar
```